# Unity C# - Issue with OnTriggerStay not being called consistently for colliders

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a Unity project where I have two game objects with colliders - one is a player character, and the other is a trigger zone. I've attached a script to the trigger zone object with the OnTriggerStay method to detect when the player is inside the trigger zone.

However, I'm facing an issue where the OnTriggerStay method is not consistently being called when the player enters and stays inside the trigger zone. It seems to work intermittently, and I'm struggling to identify the root cause.

I've ensured that both colliders have the appropriate settings, and I'm confident that the trigger zone is correctly set up. I've also checked for any potential interference from other scripts or components, but I haven't been able to pinpoint the issue.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class TriggerZone : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Player is inside the trigger zone");
            // Perform necessary actions
        }
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this inconsistency and how I can ensure that OnTriggerStay is reliably called when the player stays inside the trigger zone.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: what makes you think its not called? a common mistake is collapsed console, and so the numbers go up but people only see 1 message